# What is wrong with that when registering multiple types in Unity Container (EventAggregator and DialogService)?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am using WPF with Prism. I am totally new in MVVM, Prism, DI containers and so on. I am trying to build an app using them in order to learn and understand them.

I already use Prism's EventAggregator and it works fine. But I also need Prism's new DialogService in most of my viewmodel classes (but not all of them).

I would like to have the following:

```
        private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
        private readonly IDialogService _dialogService;

        public SomeViewModel(IEventAggregator ea, IDialogService dialog) 
        {
            // some other stuff here....

            _eventAggregator = ea;
            _dialogService = dialog;
        }
```

I found a static class somewhere on C# Corner:

```
 public static class DependencyInjector
    {
        private static readonly UnityContainer UnityContainer = new UnityContainer();
        public static void Register<I, T>() where T : I
        {
            UnityContainer.RegisterType<I, T>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        }
        public static void InjectStub<I>(I instance)
        {
            UnityContainer.RegisterInstance(instance, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        }
        public static T Retrieve<T>()
        {
            return UnityContainer.Resolve<T>();
        }
    }
```

And how I use it in App.xaml.cs:

```
  DependencyInjector.Register<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
  DependencyInjector.Register<IDialogService, DialogService>();
```

Without registering DialogService (so just using EventAggregator), this worked fine.
But now I got an exception.

How could I use it?

Comment: It's unclear what exception you get and where but why don't you register your types in the `RegisterTypes` method of the `PrismApplication` base class and use the provided container?

Comment: What is PrismApplication? I created my project as WPF  project and I added Prism.WPF as a NuGet package.

Comment: It's the class from which your `App` class should inherit. You need to set up Prism in your app to be able to use it properly.

Comment: It's inherit from Application. What should I do? I did not hove any problems whith Prism before trying to use DialogService except I am new to MVVM so it is hard for me to understand.

Comment: Install the `Prism.Unity` package, change the base class of `App` to `Prism.Unity.PrismApplication` and override the `RegisterTypes` method to register any custom type of yours. The `CreateShell()` should return an instance of your shell window.

Comment: Are there any other ways to do that?

Comment: To do what? You don't seem to know how to use Prism in the first place.

Comment: I don't know how to use MVVM and others, I am totally new to that. There is nobody to explain that, my English is very poor and I do not have enough time.
When I created my WPF app itself, it was a mistake to create a WPF app and I should create something else?
Now I can't create another project... How can register the two types in any other ways? I don't mind if it is ugly, but it should work.

Comment: I've already told how to register types using Prism, haven't I?

Comment: How can I change the base of a partial class? The other parts of this class are auto-generated. Maybe I took a mistake when I created the project itself, but I searched the internet at that time, so I don't know how could I get wrong informations. Now I think I should find a totally new way or brake MVVM rules and use MessageBox.Show in viewmodel classes.

Comment: Change `<App` to `<prism:PrismApplication` in the XAML file.

Comment: What should happen if I do this?

Answer (score 0):

> I found a static class somewhere on C# Corner: [...] And how I use it in App.xaml.cs: [...] How could I use it?

Don't. Just scrap it. Prism provides everything you need to do

```
 public SomeViewModel(IEventAggregator ea, IDialogService dialog)
```

right out of the box. Just put `ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True";` in your `SomeView`'s xaml, and Prism will magically create an instance of `SomeViewModel` with the correct constructor parameters and assign it as data context.

On a side note, people will get hurt if you just pick up and use stuff you stumble accross that you don't understand. Applies to cars and explosives as well as to code...